# What are OData Controller Life Cycle events OnExecuting / OnExecuted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

In order to do diagnostics, what are the equivalent actions to override for these two events, in OData Controller:

1. before action begins executing.
2. on action executed

   ---

I could find only one:

```
public class BaseODataController : ODataController
{
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

---

And most importantly the query filters are applied once we return the control from action, in which lifecycle event, we can measure the diagnostics: e.g. Time elapsed for a method execution.

Comment: Have you checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1 ?

Comment: You could use an action filter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define a filter:

```
public class SampleActionFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do something before the action executes
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something after the action executes
    }
}
```

Then apply attribute for action in controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController : ODataController
{
    [SampleActionFilter]
    [HttpGet("SomeResource")]
    public IActionResult SomeResource()
    {
        return Content("Successful access to resource - header should be set.");
    }
}
```

You can check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Let me know if is useful.

Comment: Your answer is right, with just a tweak, for sake of beneffit of others, rather than using just filter, use `EnableQueryAttributeFilter`